# Can't sign out of non existing sandbox account iOS 13.4

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I deleted on App Store Connect an old sandbox tester account *xxx+yyy@zzz.com that* was used for testing in app purchases and created a new one instead.

When trying to run my app on a device, I see this native dialog:

[image]

The only password that works is the one of the deleted account.

On the device's settings (iOS 13.4), under **iTunes & App Stores**, **SANDBOX ACCOUNT** is the **NEW** sandbox tester account.

I can't seem to sign out from the deleted account and use the new one for testing in app purchases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could indicate that you have unfinshed transations in your payment queue. Try if looping in `paymentQueue(_, updatedTransactions:)` through all transactions and calling `finishTransaction()` on them fixes your problem.